# I use PhpStorm and I have this problem with downloading node , npm

Tags: node.js, npm, phpstorm

I've used the following commands:

```
composer dump-autoload 
npm install -g rainbow-cli
-- loglevel=verbose
```

I'm using Mac.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please post code/errors/etc as formatted text instead of links to images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What is the specific issue? Looks like a bunch of warnings about some dependencies.